# IE browser not supporting Math.trunc()

Tags: javascript

The below code is working fine in Chrome, but in IE browser I am seeing the below console error:

> object does not support property or method 'trunc'

Code:

```
var Days = (new Date(date1) - new Date(date2)) / 50;
if (Math.trunc(Days) > 45)) {
 alert("it should be less than 45 days");
}
```

Comment: That's true, see on MDN - IE is not supported: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc

Comment: You'll need to use a polyfill to provide support in IE

Comment: Yeah polyfills are the way to go! Or have your own implementation of it.

Comment: Would [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403312/11299053) work for you?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Math.trunc` is not supported in IE as MDN states, please read [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc).

Instead you could use polifylls:

```
if (!Math.trunc) {
    Math.trunc = function (v) {
        return v < 0 ? Math.ceil(v) : Math.floor(v);
    };
}
```

Hope that clarifies.

Comment: interesting, this is much more succinct than the polyfill I use, quick question, how does it handle `NaN` - is that covered?

Comment: This returns NaN if it is passed NaN.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie : what would you say about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60403312/11299053)?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't built into the browser. You can use the following polyfill

```
Math.trunc = Math.trunc || function(x) {
  if (isNaN(x)) {
    return NaN;
  }
  if (x > 0) {
    return Math.floor(x);
  }
  return Math.ceil(x);
};
```

### Update

After seeing a much neater version from @norbitrial this can be expressed even more succinctly as

```
Math.trunc = Math.trunc || function(x) {
    return x < 0 ? Math.ceil(x) : Math.floor(x);
}
```

Comment: Technically, the check for `NaN` in your answer is redundant, as both `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil` will return NaN if passed NaN.  I think it serves as useful documentation-as-code though.

Comment: I realised that, it was me being stupid I thought `"a" < 0` would throw an error, was me being stupid, just updating my helper library now - learn shortcuts every day even after all this time :-P

Answer (score 0):

Yes, IE does not support `Math.trunc`, or many other features. See the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/trunc#Browser_compatibility) browser compatibility table.

Your options are do the logic that `.trunc` is doing your self, or use an existing polyfill.
Either way it would end up looking something like:

```
if (!Math.trunc) {
    Math.trunc = function (v) {
        return v < 0 ? Math.ceil(v) : Math.floor(v);
    };
}
```